how to handle ssh certificate based authentication from one region to another with certificate validity time?
Im trying to create an ssh certificate using keygen tool from One region(ex: india) to connect the server in another region(ex: us).
Im giving the validity for the certificate as (current time) to (curretn time + 2 hours). Ex: certificate is created with validity from (26-4-2024 00:30:00) to (26-4-2024 2:30:00) in india.
But im going to access the server in US using this certificate. current India time = 26-4-2024 00:30:00 current US time = 25-4-2024 03:00:00
The certificate created time is still 9 hours away from my current indian time. How to create the certificate with UTC? which ll be the correct solution for this problem.
I tried as given in keygen manpage. But no luck. It says invalid time format.
sample command for cert gen with UTC timezone as mentioned in keygen manpage.

ssh-keygen -s ca -I identitystring -n username -V 20100101123000Z:20110101123000Z client.pub

response:

Invalid from time "20100101123000Z"

Can anyone help with this?

Certificates usually contain timezone information. This should not be an issue.

There is an option keygen tool to give valdity with UTC format. Ref: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#V
But it didn't work. Getting invalid format error while trying it.

Then show how you tried it.

have updated in above question. Please have a look at it again.

The date is validated by int parse_absolute_time(const char *s, uint64_t *tp) function: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/misc.c#L2428

So from the code it;s clear that the manpage syntax is not possible.
Then how we could achieve UTC timezone in Certificate? @MirceaVutcovici

From what I read it should pass. Maybe you need to use more recent time.

Could you try with local time zone? Internally it's converted to UTC.

The certificates have the validity period in UTC/GMT time:
$ echo ""|openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443|&openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer -dates 
subject=CN=www.google.com
issuer=C=US, O=Google Trust Services LLC, CN=GTS CA 1C3
notBefore=Apr  8 07:33:48 2024 GMT
notAfter=Jul  1 07:33:47 2024 GMT

This means it will work independent of the timezone of the endpoints, as the validity will be checked using UTC time. You shouldn't worry about this. I think the issue is caused by something else.
To understand why the certificate is not trusted you need to check the client and server logs. Make a network capture and search for TLS ALERT error message. E.g. certificate_expired, bad_certificate, certificate_unknown, etc. For a network capture use tcpdump, dumpcap, then analyze it with WireShark.

There is an option keygen tool to give valdity with UTC format. Ref: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#V
But it didn't work. Getting invalid format error while trying it.
Unable to create cert with UTC timezone

Edit your question and add the ssh-keygen command you are using with the output. Redact any confidential information and replace with example.com or similar.

have updated in above question. Please have a look at it again. @Mircea Vutcovici
